# Kotlin bound type parameters extension overload

Tags: generics, kotlin, overloading

Is it possible to overload extension functions based on their bound type parameters? For example:

```
abstract class BaseActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    fun <T : Drawable> Int.get(): T? 
        = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this@BaseActivity, this@get) as T?
    fun <T : View> Int.get(): T 
        = findViewById(this)

}
```

Example usage:

```
R.id.webView.get<WebView>() // finds webView
R.drawable.image.get<Drawable>() // gets drawable from resources
```

(Android code is unrelated to the issue, it's just what I had)

But it gives me error:

```
Conflicting overloads: public fun <T : Drawable> Int.get(): T? defined in xxx.BaseActivity, 
public final fun <T : View> Int.get(): T defined in xxx.BaseActivity
```

Shouldn't it be possible?

Answer (score 1):

The two functions will compile down to the same function signature after the generics have been erased.

For example, this is what it might look like:

```
@NotNull
public final String get() {
  ...
}
```

The compiler has no way of knowing which function to call.

A solution to this could be reified type parameters.

```
    interface Some
    interface Other

    inline fun <reified T> get() = when (T::class) {
        Some::class -> "hey"
        Other::class -> null
        else -> throw UnsupportedOperationException()
    }
```

However then you have to lift the type restrictions.

Comment: "The two functions will compile down to the same function signature after the generics have been erased." No, they don't: the return types are different.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov The return type is not part of the signature, see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html) for example: _Definition: Two of the components of a method declaration comprise the method signature—the method's name and the parameter types._

Comment: That's true for Java language, but JVM does allow overloading based on return types (though after checking, the relevant term is "descriptor" and "signature" there includes generics as well).

Answer (score 1):

The 'normal' way with resolving platform declaration clash using `@JvmName` won't work here: Kotlin allows overloading by types of value parameters, not by bounds of type parameters.

This can be (uglily) worked around by adding useless value parameters with (just as useless) default values.

```
// unchanged
fun <T : Drawable> Int.get(): T? =
        ContextCompat.getDrawable(this@BaseActivity, this@get) as T?

// added a parameter
fun <T : View> Int.get(dummy: Nothing? = null): T =
        findViewById(this)
```

Some unrelated notes:

- such small methods should be `inline`, especially ones with default values for parameters
- `findViewById` could be replaced with [Kotlin Android extensions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html)
- [Anko](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko/) library has many useful extensions and shortcuts, including ones for fetching resources and even building layouts from code without XML

Comment: Nice. About Kotlin Android extensions, [it's no longer advocated for usage](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/ala9p2/why_kotlinx_synthetic_is_no_longer_a_recommended/)

Comment: I don't follow Google's crappy advice. They can invent and deprecate things 256 times a day while I just want to solve my problems. And no matter how good Kotlin Android extensions are, XML layouts and drawables should be burnt to the ground.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to overload extension functions based on their bound type parameters?

Generally speaking, yes. The problem is that the parameters only appear in return types, and the rules of Java (which Kotlin follows in this respect) don't allow overloading methods based on their return types, because return types aren't used for overload resolution. This decision was made before generics appeared in Java, because then the compiler could never choose a more specific method. Afterwards it could have been revised, but wasn't.

If you had a `T` *parameter*, it would work.